# return largest number of characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of numbers:

```
Numbers = [1, 34, -45]
```

I want to create a function that returns the width of the number with the largest number of characters:

For example:

```
Max_width([1, 34, -45])
```

Output:

```
3
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
def max_width(a):
    return max(len(str(x)) for x in a)

print(max_width([1, 34, -45]))
# 3
```

I don't think any explanation is needed here, but, here you go:

1. `str(x)` converts the `int` to a string. (i.e. `str(-45) = '-45'`)
2. `len(x)` returns the length of the string (or, width, as you call it)
3. `x for x in a` simply iterates over the list `a`
4. `max()` returns the max value from the list

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one too, using the `map` function:

```
def Max_width(numbers):
    return len(max(map(str,numbers), key=len))

Numbers = [1, 34, -45]

print("Max length: ", Max_width(Numbers))
```

Output:

```
Max length:  3
```